# can timestamp be stored in the mysql history file /root/.mysql_history?

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to identify the timestamp for the mysql command executed.
In the /root/.mysql_history  file there is only command and no time is found.

Can a timestamp be stored in the mysql history file /root/.mysql_history in Linux using any configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke `mysql --syslog`, the client will write a log of the queries you execute in your system log, including the date & time.

On Linux this log is in /var/log/messages. On Mac, it's /var/log/system.log. On Windows, it's the Windows Event Log.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-logging.html

You can also enable this option by default by editing `/etc/my.cnf` or your personal `$HOME/.my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
syslog
```

I tried this in my VM, and I got the following in /var/log/messages. I tried twice, once using the command-line option and then with the config-file option.

```
Sep 19 16:09:30 sandbox-centos mysql: SYSTEM_USER:'vagrant', MYSQL_USER:'root', CONNECTION_ID:215, DB_SERVER:'127.0.0.1', DB:'--', QUERY:'select 'now is the time';'
Sep 19 16:10:02 sandbox-centos mysql: SYSTEM_USER:'vagrant', MYSQL_USER:'root', CONNECTION_ID:223, DB_SERVER:'127.0.0.1', DB:'--', QUERY:'select now();'
```

Of course any user can override this option, so it's pretty easy to cover one's tracks. In other words, you shouldn't rely on this as an auditing tool.